# D3.js How to hide/show line when click select options?

Tags: d3.js

I tried to use D3.js to draw lines when you click on different checkbox. It will get data of that option. Here is an example I used [D3 multi-series line chart with tooltips and legend](http://bl.ocks.org/Matthew-Weber/5645518). I have got the specific data object that is corresponding the checkbox I choose. Howevery, I don't know how to draw it on svg. Please help me and I will appreciate you so much.

I also find a website "www.cotrino.com/starpaths/" that shows the final effect I want to implement.

[My D3 effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSAT9.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.axis--x path {
 display: none;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<body>
<svg width="1000" height="500"></svg>
<div id="disease_list"></div>

</body>




<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


 //make a clip path for the graph  
 var clip = svg.append("svg:clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
    .append("svg:rect")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);   

var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m");


var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]),
y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

var line = d3.line()
    .curve(d3.curveBasis)
    .x(function(d) { console.log(d.date); return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { console.log(d.date); return y(d.count); });

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);



d3.csv("./top10highestNormalize.csv", type, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var diseases = data.columns.slice(1).map(function(id) {
    return {
      id: id,
      values: data.map(function(d) {
        return {date: d.date, count: d[id]};
      })
    };
  });

  console.log(diseases);

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));

  y.domain([
    d3.min(diseases, function(c) { return d3.min(c.values, function(d) { return d.count; }); }),
    d3.max(diseases, function(c) { return d3.max(c.values, function(d) { return d.count; }); })
  ]);


  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", "0.71em")
      .attr("fill", "#000")
      .text("Count");

  /*
      var disease = g.selectAll(".disease")
    .data(diseases)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "disease");
*/
  // Create the shape selectors
  var selector = d3.select("#disease_list").append("select");

  labels = selector.selectAll("option")
      .data(diseases)
      .enter()
      .append("option")
      .attr("value",function(d,i) {return i;})
      .text(function(d) {return d.id;});

  var menu = d3.select("#disease_list select")
               .on("change", redraw);  

     // var series = menu.property("value");

      //console.log(series);


      // all the meat goes in the redraw function
      function redraw() { 

        console.log("redraw start");

          // get value from menu selection
          // the option values are set in HTML and correspond
          //to the [type] value we used to nest the data  
          var series = menu.property("value");
          console.log(series);

          // only retrieve data from the selected series, using the nest we just created
          var adata = diseases[series];

          console.log(adata);


         }


});

function type(d, _, columns) {
  d.date = parseTime(d.date);
  for (var i = 1, n = columns.length, c; i < n; ++i) d[c = columns[i]] = +d[c];
  return d;
}

</script>
```

top10highestNormalize.csv

```
date,disseminated sclerosis,sclerosis,gestural tics,venereal disease,bite,cot death,venereal disease,cardiovascular disease,diseases vascular,pruritis,pus,cystic fibrosis,fibroses
2010-04,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
2010-05,0,0,0.06898023,0.068783069,0.085790885,0.065761258,0.068783069,0,0,0.001204094,0.023051592,0,0
2010-06,0.076923077,0.076923077,0.190584554,0.199972867,0.201072386,0.171789373,0.199972867,0.071428571,0.071428571,0.004816376,0.031284303,0.2,0.2
2010-07,0.230769231,0.230769231,0.221590101,0.224664225,0.225201072,0.235167977,0.224664225,0.214285714,0.285714286,0.00602047,0.038419319,0,0
2010-08,0.538461538,0.538461538,0.174797326,0.182471849,0.174262735,0.192041935,0.182471849,0.071428571,0.071428571,0.003612282,0.023051592,0,0
2010-09,0.230769231,0.230769231,0.287725786,0.277845611,0.252010724,0.259471051,0.277845611,0,0,0.004214329,0.046652031,0,0
2010-10,0.076923077,0.076923077,0.295406059,0.299416633,0.285969616,0.265665952,0.299416633,0,0.071428571,0.007224564,0.03402854,0.066666667,0.066666667
2010-11,0.153846154,0.153846154,0.284027877,0.279337946,0.261840929,0.276149631,0.279337946,0,0,0.006622517,0.050493963,0,0
2010-12,0.153846154,0.153846154,0.271511876,0.237552571,0.213583557,0.237312366,0.237552571,0.142857143,0.142857143,0.004214329,0.035126235,0,0
2011-01,0.076923077,0.076923077,0.306642014,0.312440646,0.28150134,0.305694544,0.312440646,0.142857143,0.142857143,0.006622517,0.046103183,0,0.066666667
2011-02,0.076923077,0.076923077,0.288721377,0.262243929,0.219839142,0.25899452,0.262243929,0.142857143,0.142857143,0.007224564,0.038968167,0,0.066666667
2011-03,0.076923077,0.076923077,0.271654103,0.255324922,0.253798034,0.266857279,0.255324922,0.071428571,0.071428571,0.007224564,0.051591658,0,0
2011-04,0.461538462,0.461538462,0.291423695,0.252068919,0.235031278,0.284250655,0.252068919,0,0,0.009030704,0.045005488,0,0
2011-05,0.153846154,0.153846154,0.448158157,0.380681047,0.351206434,0.439123183,0.380681047,0,0,0.011438892,0.079582876,0.333333333,0.4
2011-06,0.153846154,0.153846154,0.498079932,0.437661104,0.391420912,0.424827258,0.437661104,0.142857143,0.142857143,0.009632751,0.063117453,0,0.066666667
2011-07,0,0,0.410467928,0.424094424,0.419124218,0.379080295,0.424094424,0,0.071428571,0.009030704,0.061470911,1,1
2011-08,0.076923077,0.076923077,0.268382876,0.262922263,0.238605898,0.267810341,0.262922263,0.214285714,0.214285714,0.002408188,0.038968167,0,0
2011-09,0.230769231,0.230769231,0.510027023,0.469949803,0.470956211,0.444841553,0.469949803,0,0,0.014449127,0.075740944,0.133333333,0.2
2011-10,0.076923077,0.076923077,0.462380885,0.434540768,0.431635389,0.417679295,0.434540768,0.142857143,0.142857143,0.006622517,0.073545554,0,0.066666667
2011-11,0.153846154,0.153846154,0.519698478,0.457061457,0.415549598,0.443888492,0.457061457,0.142857143,0.142857143,0.01384708,0.06805708,0.2,0.2
2011-12,1,1,0.382449154,0.35002035,0.319928508,0.315701692,0.35002035,0,0,0.002408188,0.060373216,0,0
2012-01,0.461538462,0.461538462,0.492390841,0.45312712,0.409294013,0.45389564,0.45312712,0.571428571,0.571428571,0.007224564,0.060373216,0,0
2012-02,0.076923077,0.076923077,0.382875836,0.375932709,0.350312779,0.369073147,0.375932709,0.071428571,0.071428571,0.003612282,0.049945115,0.066666667,0.066666667
2012-03,0.923076923,1,1,0.922127255,1,0.871098404,0.922127255,0.5,0.5,0.01384708,0.171789243,0,0.066666667
2012-04,0.230769231,0.307692308,0.699331532,0.676977344,0.63360143,0.645699309,0.676977344,0.142857143,0.142857143,0.012040939,0.092206367,0.133333333,0.133333333
2012-05,0.846153846,0.846153846,0.801735173,0.752408086,0.776586238,0.7436264,0.752408086,0.785714286,0.785714286,0.016857315,0.131723381,0.466666667,0.466666667
2012-06,0.384615385,0.461538462,0.730479306,0.732193732,0.625558534,0.657850846,0.732193732,0,0,0.011438892,0.118002195,0.6,0.666666667
2012-07,0.384615385,0.384615385,0.751386716,0.738434405,0.71849866,0.714081487,0.738434405,0.285714286,0.285714286,0.009030704,0.126783754,0.2,0.2
2012-08,0.384615385,0.461538462,0.700327123,0.643467643,0.619302949,0.646890636,0.643467643,0.285714286,0.285714286,0.012642986,0.150933041,0.2,0.266666667
2012-09,0.076923077,0.230769231,0.72137676,0.701804368,0.63538874,0.70455087,0.701804368,0.214285714,0.214285714,0.011438892,0.130076839,0.066666667,0.066666667
2012-10,0.230769231,0.230769231,0.846252311,0.863112196,0.796246649,0.825827972,0.863112196,0.071428571,0.071428571,0.036724865,0.127881449,0.333333333,0.333333333
2012-11,0.692307692,0.692307692,0.895605177,1,0.798927614,0.909935668,1,0.214285714,0.357142857,0.012642986,0.143798024,0,0.133333333
2012-12,0.923076923,1,0.795903854,0.803283137,0.683646113,0.827257565,0.803283137,0.142857143,0.142857143,0.008428657,0.104829857,0.6,0.6
2013-01,0.230769231,0.384615385,0.92106386,0.964862298,0.848078642,0.944007624,0.964862298,0.285714286,0.357142857,0.015653221,0.146542261,0.533333333,0.733333333
2013-02,0.153846154,0.307692308,0.830322856,0.872880206,0.798927614,0.755777937,0.872880206,0.142857143,0.142857143,0.010234798,0.110318332,0,0.066666667
2013-03,0.230769231,0.230769231,0.927037406,0.944105277,0.885612154,0.953061711,0.944105277,0.142857143,0.142857143,0.009632751,0.131174533,0,0.133333333
2013-04,0.384615385,0.384615385,0.796046082,0.775471442,0.671134942,0.715749345,0.775471442,0,0,0.012040939,0.12349067,0.133333333,0.133333333
2013-05,0.923076923,1,0.824633765,0.844254511,0.742627346,0.843697879,0.844254511,0.142857143,0.142857143,0.015653221,0.149286498,0,0
2013-06,0.307692308,0.307692308,0.884369222,0.949667616,0.865951743,1,0.949667616,0.071428571,0.071428571,0.020469597,0.135016465,0.466666667,0.466666667
2013-07,0.461538462,0.461538462,0.864172948,0.935829602,0.843610366,0.939480581,0.935829602,0.071428571,0.071428571,0.015051174,0.128979144,0.066666667,0.2
2013-08,0.153846154,0.153846154,0.670886076,0.738163071,0.753351206,0.821300929,0.738163071,0.071428571,0.214285714,0.012642986,0.098243688,0,0
2013-09,0.230769231,0.230769231,0.876262267,0.861484195,0.744414656,0.996426019,0.861484195,0,0,0.024081878,0.144895719,0.066666667,0.066666667
2013-10,0.615384615,0.615384615,0.917508178,0.885361552,0.806970509,0.841315225,0.885361552,0.642857143,0.642857143,0.030704395,0.115806806,0.2,0.4
2013-11,0,0.076923077,0.857061584,0.903540904,0.791778374,0.845127472,0.903540904,0.5,0.5,0.012642986,0.093852909,0,0
2013-12,0.230769231,0.230769231,0.704878396,0.719169719,0.584450402,0.81915654,0.719169719,0.285714286,0.5,0.015653221,0.108122942,0,0
2014-01,0.461538462,0.461538462,0.900014223,0.856328856,0.717605004,0.98903979,0.856328856,0.357142857,0.5,0.030102348,0.137211855,0,0.066666667
2014-02,0,0,0.707865169,0.703296703,0.63717605,0.796997856,0.703296703,1,1,0.012642986,0.097145993,0,0
2014-03,0.230769231,0.230769231,0.815531219,0.800434134,0.7256479,0.786275911,0.800434134,0.714285714,0.714285714,0.009632751,0.099341383,0.533333333,0.6
2014-04,0.153846154,0.153846154,0.756506898,0.790259124,0.615728329,0.778174887,0.790259124,0,0,0.011438892,0.12349067,0,0
2014-05,0.461538462,0.461538462,0.85990613,0.767331434,0.705987489,0.78008101,0.767331434,0.142857143,0.285714286,0.014449127,0.13611416,0.066666667,0.133333333
2014-06,0.076923077,0.153846154,0.670886076,0.713064713,0.615728329,0.735763641,0.713064713,0.285714286,0.285714286,0.010836845,0.102634468,0,0
2014-07,0.076923077,0.076923077,0.672592803,0.801655135,0.621090259,0.680009531,0.801655135,0.071428571,0.071428571,0.007224564,0.103183315,0,0
2014-08,0.384615385,0.461538462,0.487270659,0.58377425,0.486148347,0.575887539,0.58377425,0.071428571,0.071428571,0.005418423,0.079582876,0,0.133333333
2014-09,0,0.076923077,0.715545442,0.678062678,0.669347632,0.705980462,0.678062678,0,0,0.01384708,0.103183315,0,0.066666667
2014-10,0.230769231,0.307692308,0.742995306,0.723511057,0.630920465,0.679294734,0.723511057,0,0,0.016857315,0.1064764,0,0
2014-11,0,0,0.672735031,0.623388957,0.583556747,0.64927329,0.623388957,0,0,0.004816376,0.115806806,0.066666667,0.066666667
2014-12,0.307692308,0.384615385,0.591096572,0.55704789,0.478999106,0.491303312,0.55704789,0.285714286,0.428571429,0.003010235,0.074643249,0,0
2015-01,0.076923077,0.153846154,0.659223439,0.561117894,0.531724754,0.605432452,0.561117894,0.071428571,0.071428571,0.007224564,0.094401756,0.133333333,0.133333333
2015-02,0.230769231,0.307692308,0.61840421,0.564780898,0.512064343,0.585656421,0.564780898,0.071428571,0.071428571,0.007224564,0.096597146,0,0
2015-03,0,0,0.770302944,0.677927011,0.599642538,0.675482487,0.677927011,0.071428571,0.071428571,0.009632751,0.111964874,0.066666667,0.2
2015-04,0.076923077,0.076923077,0.706016214,0.61687695,0.731903485,0.563497736,0.61687695,0.071428571,0.071428571,0.008428657,0.097145993,0,0
2015-05,0,0.076923077,0.655383303,0.614027947,0.55406613,0.6154396,0.614027947,0.071428571,0.071428571,0.012642986,0.099341383,0,0
2015-06,0,0.076923077,0.564357844,0.540632207,0.527256479,0.598284489,0.540632207,0.142857143,0.142857143,0.00602047,0.091657519,0,0
2015-07,0.076923077,0.076923077,0.486417295,0.525301859,0.511170688,0.566356922,0.525301859,0,0,0.015653221,0.08726674,0.066666667,0.066666667
2015-08,0.230769231,0.230769231,0.408476746,0.386379053,0.320822163,0.465094115,0.386379053,0,0,0.003010235,0.056531284,0,0
2015-09,0.538461538,0.538461538,0.870999858,0.792701126,0.747095621,0.883964737,0.792701126,0,0,0.013245033,0.156421515,0,0
2015-10,0.153846154,0.153846154,0.469492249,0.435490435,0.320822163,0.51227067,0.435490435,0,0,0.174593618,0.221734358,0,0
2015-11,0.153846154,0.153846154,0.322998151,0.309455976,0.273458445,0.346676197,0.309455976,0,0,0.462974112,0.481888035,0.133333333,0.133333333
2015-12,0.076923077,0.076923077,0.342767743,0.309320309,0.27971403,0.384798666,0.309320309,0,0,0.464780253,0.482436883,0.066666667,0.066666667
2016-01,0.307692308,0.384615385,0.415872564,0.349477683,0.358355675,0.442458899,0.349477683,0,0,0.559903672,0.581229418,0.066666667,0.066666667
2016-02,0,0,0.445455838,0.403744404,0.316353887,0.457469621,0.403744404,0,0,0.54846478,0.568605928,0.066666667,0.066666667
2016-03,0,0,0.471198976,0.400352734,0.317247542,0.508220157,0.400352734,0.142857143,0.142857143,0.604455148,0.628430296,0,0
2016-04,0,0,0.582989617,0.570343237,0.575513852,0.603764594,0.570343237,0.214285714,0.214285714,1,1,0,0
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your line variable:

```
var myLine = svg.append("path");
```

And then, inside `redraw()`, changing it according to the option selected:

```
myLine.datum(adata.values)
    .attr("d", line);
```

Here is a demo plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/YjGO9TLDBXj13JQuO5bm?p=preview

**PS**: I changed your x-scale range:

```
var x = d3.scaleTime().range([margin.left, width]);
```

And also added a call to `redraw()` when the code runs for the first time.